# What are the critical values of α where the qualitative nature of the phase portrait for the system changes?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was given a matrix and solved for the eigenvalues and were marked as correct but I dont know how to solve for the second part of my question. Help please.

$r = -1 + \dfrac{\sqrt{100 + 44 \alpha}}{2}$

$r_2 = -1 - \dfrac{\sqrt{100 + 44 \alpha}}{2}$

Please help me with these questions:

The roots are complex when?

There is a saddle point for?

The equilibrium point is a stable node where?

I tried solving the problem and got the values of -24/11, -25/11 and -26/11 but the were all wrong. How would i solve for these three questions?

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.